# debugging myprog.f90 using gdb: break line errs "No line in file"

Tags: gdb, break, fortran90

I am using gdb to debug a fortran90 program, myprog.f90, that uses some modules, say mod1 and mod2.

I launch gdb...
$ gdb ./program

and try to set a line break...
(gdb) break 80

but I receive the error "No line 80 in file 'mod1.f90'".
So although I am trying to set a line break in myprog.f90, it's trying to set the line break in the first module of the program mod1.

How do I break a line in and step through myprog.f90?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
(gdb) break myprog.f90:80
```

See also [documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html) on setting breakpoints, and on [location](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html) specification.